# "Without selection" vs. "without a selection"

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

> 1. W is the complex-valued transformation of the original signals x and y without selection of the window length with respect to time t.
> 2. W is the complex-valued transformation of the original signals x and y without **a** selection of the window length with respect to time t.

Which is correct?

Comment: First, *"a"* is an article or determiner, not a preposition. Both sentences are correct; whether you want *"a"* or not here depends on context. But I don't understand what possible context could make this sentence meaningful. If there is a window length (which this statement implies), there is some mechanism by which it was selected. There is also a serious ambiguity: does *"with respect to time t"* modify "*selection of the window length*" or *complex-valued transformation"*?

Comment: Maybe you mean *without a specified window length*? (This would mean that whatever program you're using to do the transformation chose the default window length, which I would assume is the length of the data series.) It would be better to say what the actual default action of the program is, unless it will be obvious to the readers of the paper.

Comment: @PeterShor There is no need to select any window length, because the window is never applied. This is the point.

Comment: then "without (a) selection of the window length" is the wrong way to phrase it; what you need to say is "with no window applied". If you say "without a selection of the window length", that means that there is a window, but its length wasn't selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) is correct for the usage I presume you want here.

*A selection* implies that you are taking a sampling of window lengths from a greater pool. (*e.g.* A selection of fine chocolates.)

Omitting *a* in this case gives us the correct meaning:  W is the variable without specifying the length of the window.

I understand what you were trying to accomplish by saying *a selection*, but that would be a better place to use *selecting*.

In fact, I would argue that *specifying the window length* or *selecting the window length* is probably better usage here anyway.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `without specifying the window length`

Comment: Can you omit "a" without changing the verb to "selecting" or "specifying"?

Comment: @MrHen I would say you could.  The sentence becomes *without (the) selection*.  Again, it forces me to defend an inferior construct, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this question because your sentence is so long. Attempting to trim it down is also difficult because there are a few possibilities:

> 1. W is the transformation without selection of the window length.
> 2. W is the transformation of the (signals x and y without selection of the window length.)
> 3. W is the transformation without selection of (the window length with respect to time t.)

In all three cases, the meaning of "selection" is unclear without further context. My best guess, based on your comments above, is that the appropriate word is actually "any":

> W is the transformation without any selection of the window length.

If you reworded it slightly then the answer to your original question is more obvious:

> W is the transformation without any window length selection.

In this sense, it would be more appropriate to use "a". Therefore, the correct usage is with an "a".

Comment: I don't know that you can trim a mathematical description without paring off its meaning.

Comment: I am working with what was provided; the asker can add additional context if they want me to avoid butchering the (mathematical) context.